# Why does margin-top on this page push down more than just the div it's in?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

http://christianselig.com/wp

I have a `margin-top: 50px` set to the .greeting class div, which is basically the big greeting image. But for whatever reason, it drags down the previous nav element for some reason, even though they're not attached.

On my main site, http://christianselig.com, I have it (without Wordpress implementation), so I'm confused what's different here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Used to this  css**   **clear** your header `id`

```
#masthead.site-header:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Result is

[image]

Comment: He might as well use a reusable `clearfix` class instead of tying this technique to a specific element.

Comment: Different variants of "the clearfix hack": http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Comment: @AymanSafadi if you define oveflow:hiden in this id #masthead than shadow effect is not show

Comment: @AymanSafadi if your define overflow hidden than result is this http://i.stack.imgur.com/RvSct.png ....

Answer (score 1):

## [Margin Collapse](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)

> The top margin of an in-flow block element collapses with its first in-flow block-level child's top margin if the element has no top border, no top padding, and the child has no clearance.

As a gross oversimplification:

- margins between sibling elements (top & bottom) will collapse to the size of the larger margin.
- margins in the same direction (top & bottom) between ancestor/descendant elements will collapse to the size of the larger margin if there is no padding, or border

Answer (score 0):

The `#masthead` is collapsing since all of its' children (in this case only one) are floating, and therefore losing it's *layout* properties.

Add this:

```
#masthead {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

---

Alternatively, remove the `float` property in your `.main-navigation` rule and replace it with `overflow: hidden;` instead. I don's see a reason why this should be floating anyways.

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by collapsing margins, but it's somewhat unintuitive because the margin of your main content is collapsing with the `<header>` element above it.  This happens because your header (`#masthead`) is ending up with zero-height.  To correct this, just add `overflow:hidden` to the `#masthead` header element.

```
#masthead { overflow:hidden; }
```

That will cause #masthead to expand to include the floated `nav` element it contains, which in turn will prevent the margin from collapsing onto the #masthead header.